# libGDX actor would not behave corectly on movement

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to make actor move randomly each X seconds. The code for act is like this:

```
@Override
public void act(float delta)
{
    super.act(delta);

    if (delta > (float)(rand.nextInt(5)+3))
    {
        switch(rand.nextInt(3))
        {
            case 0:
                moveBy(3,0);
                break;
            case 1:
                moveBy(-3,0);
                break;
            case 2:
                moveBy(0,3);
                break;
            case 3:
                moveBy(0,-3);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Debug shows only X increasing overtime, and it stops on ~103. What can the problem be?
Random is inited in constructor with System.currentTimeMillis() seed.

Comment: Not sure why it's moving at all. `delta` is time since last frame, so it will usually be something like `0.016667f`. So your if statement should never execute. Also, `nextInt` is exclusive, so `nextInt(3)` is a number from 0 to 2, so case 3 would never execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello sorry for my English test this simple example aver if you want, change the final variable to adjust.

```
private Random random= new Random();

private float inttt = 0;

private float tiempo = 0;

private int randomT = 0;

private int randomN = 0;

private final int MAXTIEMPO = 15; // cambiar para aumentar o disminuir el tiempo que pasa como maximo entre un movimiento y otro.//changed to increase or decrease the time spent at most from one movement to another.

public int RandomNumber(float delta){

    tiempo += delta;

        if(randomT == 0 || randomN == 0){

                random.setSeed(System.nanoTime() * (long)inttt);
                this.randomN = random.nextInt(MAXTIEMPO);
                inttt += randomN;
                randomT = randomN;

                Gdx.app.log("randomN", ""+randomN);
                Gdx.app.log("randomT", ""+randomT);
                Gdx.app.log("tiempo", ""+tiempo);

                return 0;

        }else if(randomT != 0 && tiempo >= randomT){

                tiempo = 0;
                randomT = 0;

                Gdx.app.log("randomN", ""+randomN);
                Gdx.app.log("randomT", ""+randomT);
                Gdx.app.log("tiempo", ""+tiempo);

                return randomN;

        }else{

                Gdx.app.log("randomN", ""+randomN);
                Gdx.app.log("randomT", ""+randomT);
                Gdx.app.log("tiempo", ""+tiempo);

                return 0;
        }
    }
```

@Override
public void act(float delta)
{
    super.act(delta);

```
    if (RandomNumber(delta) != 0){

        switch(rand.nextInt(4)){

        case 0:
            moveBy(3,0);
            break;
        case 1:
            moveBy(-3,0);
            break;
        case 2:
            moveBy(0,3);
            break;
        case 3:
            moveBy(0,-3);
            break;
    }
    }
```